# signal sigbart error when using NSTimer within a touches began function

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer, touchesbegan

Im trying to build an app and when the screen is first touched it starts an NSTimer, but using an NSTimer within the touches began function I get a signal sigbart error. If anyone has any alternate methods I could use to get the same outcome I would appreciate it.

This is my basic current code

```
    var condition = 0

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    if(condition == 1) {
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("timerUpdate"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    cat.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
    cat.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 1))


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the function `timerUpdate` for the selector.

```
 override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    if(condition == 1) {
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("timerUpdate"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    cat.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
    cat.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 1))
}

func timerUpdate(){
    print("timerUpdate")
}
```

Comment: LOL thanks so much I feel kind of dumb for not doing that but oh well. Anyway thanks very much.